# Clarification about a proof of the dimension theorem.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

This was the proof I saw:

[Simplest Proof of the Dimensions theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1558688/simplest-proof-of-the-dimensions-theorem)

But why is T  injective on $\operatorname{span}(v_{p + 1}, \dots, v_n)$?

What I understand is that because the vectors spaned by the $\operatorname{span}(v_{p + 1}, \dots, v_n)$, do not belong in the kernel of $T$, each of them should land in an unique vector in the image of $T$. My question is why not being in the kernel gives the vector this property that it lands it in a unique image vector?

Comment: This is by construction when they extend the basis vectors.

Comment: So you mean extending the bases that span the kernal to the bases that span the domain of T ensures you that the images of the vectors what are expanding the bases are linearly independent. Can you elaborate further in this topic.

Comment: You've got the right idea. They're extending the basis to cover the orthogonal compliment of the kernel, which is isomorphic to the image of $T$. That isomorphism is why the counting argument works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the wording of the linked answer is not really precise (the $\oplus$ symbol is not used correctly).

Anyway, if $v\in\operatorname{span}(v_{p+1},\dots,v_n)$ and $v\in\ker T$, then you have
\begin{align}
v&=\alpha_{p+1}v_{p+1}+\dots+\alpha_nv_n \\
&=\alpha_1v_1+\dots+\alpha_pv_p
\end{align}
by definition of span. Hence
$$
\alpha_1v_1+\dots+\alpha_pv_p-\alpha_{p+1}v_{p+1}-\dots-\alpha_nv_n=0
$$
and so all those coefficients are zero. This proves $v=0$, so indeed $T$ is injective on $\operatorname{span}(v_{p+1},\dots,v_n)$.

Therefore, as
$$
T(V)=\operatorname{span}(T(v_1),\dots,T(v_p),T(v_{p+1}),\dots,T(v_n))
=\operatorname{span}(T(v_{p+1}),\dots,T(v_n))
$$
you have $\dim T(V)=n-p$.